# Calculating resistor end-of-life drift in the worst case analysis

Tags: resistors, tolerance

How is it possible to calculate the tolerance of the end-of-life based on this datasheet?

https://www.vishay.com/docs/53046/pfrr.pdf

My specs are -30°C to 60°C and I want to estimate the drift/ tolerance of the 221 Ohm resistor from the Vishay PFRR series. I researched and found some links, however, I still do not know how to use the datasheet for my goals.

I found this link
https://www.vishay.com/docs/28809/driftcalculation.pdf
however, I still do not know how to use the datasheet to calculate it.

I also found this link
http://escies.org/ftp/ecss.nl/TMs/ECSS-Q-TM-30-12A(12October2010).pdf
but they categorize everything as far as I understood and refer to 1) Time law: the cubic root of time and 2)Temperature law: Arrhenius, Ea= 0,28 eV.

How can I use this one for three years tho based on the datasheet?

As far as I understood there are several methods to calculate the drift /tolerance and I do not know how to do none of them.

To be more clear, I want to see how to calculate the aging drift so I can make a table like Table 2 in https://les-electroniciens.com/sites/default/files/cours/wcca.pdf

Please let me know if you are aware of it.

Comment: As far as I am aware you shouldn't need to worry about resistor drift within 3 years. That is as long as you are using it within spec.

Comment: What your spec tolerances?

Comment: I suspect you're going to end up with a bit of circular reasoning.  For example, if you consider a 5% tolerance on a resistor to be acceptable, then the tolerance at the end of life is 5%, because as soon as the resistor has drifted by 5.1% then it must be end-of-life, because it's out of tolerance.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I am doing a worst-case analysis under the mentioned circumstances so I need to eventually estimate the worst case. Calculating the aging drift is independent of the initial tolerance. To be more clear, I want to see how the aging drift is calculated so I can make a table like Table 2 in https://les-electroniciens.com/sites/default/files/cours/wcca.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you had an expensive 0.1% tolerance resistor, you might be concerned.

The drift is given for burst loads a 70% power or P70 and and aging rate of 30’C rise per order of magnitude reduction in MTBF.

What you ought to learn is that Resistors are usually rated for 125’C or a 100’C rise above 25’C, while 85’C will burn your finger but is an acceptable good design limit.  That would be 65% rated P above 25’C

If you were really concerned about drift, you would choose a larger power rating and not exceed 50’C and could ignore the PPM drift in the next 10 years.

But if you only need 1% tolerance chances are very high that it will always stay within tolerance if you limit T max to 60’C.

Comment: I think my message is not clear. I want to calculate the total tolerance of this resistor considering several parameters to use in the worst-case analysis. In this post, I am mainly interested to know the aging drift, e.g., after three years. An example of what I need, aging drift, is in Table 2 in [link](https://les-electroniciens.com/sites/default/files/cours/wcca.pdf). I want to know how to calculate the aging drift based on the datasheet after a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

For the formula fromthe vishay datasheet:

- t: Actual time of operation: Sum time how long is the resistor "in use" = biased over livetime. for example: 60%useage * 3years * 365days * 24hours
- Reference time of operation, Reference film temperature: from the
  Datasheet page 5 "Load life"
- Actual film temperature: You know the resistor value and the current that flows in your design so you know the power_loss. Use the power derating curve from page 4 to calculate back to the temperature rise of the resistor. for 0402: (155°C-70°C)/0,0625W * power_loss. Then add the actual PCB temperature to get the Actual film temperature

The actual PCB temperature is a bit hard to estimate as it depends on your systems surrunding.

- A wireless router will most likely have a quite constant temperature
  over lifetime. for example 30°C
- A vehicle does not have this as it can operate at -20°C (10%
  lifetime), 50°C (70% lifetime) or +60°C (20% lifetime). I would use the mean temperature over lifetime.